# Where to find Win32 Disk Imager or an alternative when you don't trust Sourceforge

Tags: windows, sd-card, disk-image

I need Win32 Disk Imager in order to write Raspbian on an SD Card. It seems the place to find that software is Sourceforge, which nowaday can hardly be considered a safe place to download software. Is there another place I can find Win32 Disk Imager, or maybe do youknow an alternative software which could let me do what I need?

Comment: Download and compile the source yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WIN32DISKIMAGER:**
This utility is used to read and write raw image files to SD and USB memory devices.
Simply run the utility, point it at your raw image, and then select the
removable device to write to.

This utility can not write CD-ROMs.  USB Floppy is NOT supported at this time.

You can download from here - https://win32diskimager.org

Answer (score 1):

For windows i only know one alternative:
http://www.roadkil.net/program.php/P12/Disk%20Image

Answer (score 1):

HDD Raw Copy Tool
https://hddguru.com/software/HDD-Raw-Copy-Tool/

Developer: HDDGURU.COM

License terms: Freeware

Supported OS: MS Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, Server 2003, 2008, 2008R2
HDD Raw Copy Tool is a utility for low-level, sector-by-sector hard disk duplication and image creation.

Supported interfaces: S-ATA (SATA), IDE (E-IDE), SCSI, SAS, USB, FIREWIRE.
Big drives (LBA-48) are supported.
Supported HDD/SSD Manufacturers: Intel, OCZ, Samsung, Kingston, Maxtor, Hitachi, Seagate, Samsung, Toshiba, Fujitsu, IBM, Quantum, Western Digital, and almost any other not listed here.
The program also supports low-level duplication of FLASH cards (SD/MMC, MemoryStick, CompactFlash, SmartMedia, XD) using a card-reader.
HDD Raw Copy tool makes an exact duplicate of a SATA, IDE, SAS, SCSI or SSD hard disk drive. Will also work with any USB and FIREWIRE external drive enclosures as well as SD, MMC, MemoryStick and CompactFlash media.

The tool creates a sector-by-sector copy of all areas of the hard drive (MBR, boot records, all partitions as well as space in between). HDD Raw Copy does not care about the operating system on the drive – it could be Windows, Linux, Mac, or any other OS with any number of partitions (including hidden ones). Bad sectors are skipped by the tool.