# Win32 Disk Imager error writing image

Tags: windows, windows-10, sd-card, disk-image

I want to install Linux on my Minix Neo x7 and [here](http://www.cnx-software.com/2014/07/02/easy-and-safe-way-to-try-linux-on-popular-rockchip-rk3188-mini-pcs/) I've found that I can do it by writing the Linux on the SD-Card.

In the tutorial it says to "Win32 Disk Imager", but I am using windows 10-x64 and "Win32 Disk Imager" shows me an error when I want to run it (setup is OK).

[image]

How do I resolve this?

P.S: I've found this link: [Where to find Win32 Disk Imager or an alternative when you don't trust Sourceforge](https://superuser.com/questions/950723/where-to-find-win32-disk-imager-or-an-alternative-when-you-dont-trust-sourcefor)  but the only shared file is from 2010

Comment: What error message did you get when you run Win32DiskImager? I got Win10 64 bit and it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: @Darius thanks for the reply. it says  unable to execute file. (I've added the image to the question)

Comment: As the error message indicated - Operation requires elevation. You need to run Win32DiskImages as Admin. Right click on it and choose "Run as Administrator" and it will work